# How to check whether user has disable the downloadmanager

Tags: android

I use system's download manager to get files from server, but some user may disable the function of download manager in his/her mobile. So how can I check this situation in my app using program, then give tips to help user enable it? Thanks.

Here some sample code of my program:

```
private long downloadFile(Context context, String downloadUrl, String destFilename, boolean showNotify) {
    // ...         

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(downloadUrl.trim()));
    request.setTitle(destFilename);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, null, destFilename);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(showNotify ? DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE :
            DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);

    // get the downloadManager
    mDownloadManager = (DownloadManager) getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    long downloadId = mDownloadManager.enqueue(request);
    VLog.r(TAG, " downloadFile id : " + downloadId + " url : " + downloadUrl);
    downloadIds.put(downloadId, downloadUrl);

    return downloadId;
}
```

Comment: One solution would be to detect whether the download manager package is installed through the PackageManager's method "getApplicationEnabledSetting". The drawback is that you have to get the package's name and i assume it can vary from a phone to another...

Answer (score 0):

After reading the source code, I get a idea to check this situation. Since DownloadManager is realized based on ContentProvider, I try to get the "ContentProviderClient" of DownloadManager. If failed, it mean something wrong with the DownloadManager. Here the sample code.

```
public static boolean isDownloadManagerEnable() {
    ContentProviderClient client = Util.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(Uri.parse("content://downloads/my_downloads").getAuthority());
    return client != null;
}
```